# WCF Web Service with Asynchronous task

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, wcf, asynchronous

I have a WCF web service which must act like this:

1. It is called from outside
2. it returns the response to the client with basic validation on input data
3. it starts an asyncronous task with must not be notified to the client.

The client must only receive response in step2, then nothing else. I think this isn't a real asynchronous web service, but a synchronous web service with asynchronous thread.

I use .NET 4.0.

What technique can I use?

Comment: I'm trying to use Task based approach but i'm not sure i can send the response in step 2 before completition of step3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not supposed to do that. For example, if your WCF service is hosted in ASP.NET, then ASP.NET will assume that it's *not doing anything* when there are no outstanding requests. So your service can be recycled while you're still doing work.

The proper architecture for this is to have a separate "backend" system for the processing (e.g., an Azure WebJob, or a Win32 Service), and put a reliable queue in-between the WCF service and the backend service (e.g., an Azure queue or MSMQ). When the WCF app receives a request, it verifies the arguments,  pops a message on the queue, and returns. Independently, the backend service reads the requests from the queue and processes them.

I have [a blog post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html) that goes into more detail, and describes a few other alternative approaches.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use async/await in your service you'll need the async pump described here:

[Await, SynchronizationContext, and Console Apps: Part 3 by Stephen Toub](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/02/02/10263555.aspx)